# Getting “No Wifi adaptor found” for ubuntu 18.04 in DELL precision

Tags: 18.04, wireless, dell, iwlwifi

I use DELL Precision 3541.
Wifi Adapter of [Intel's Wireless-AC 9560]

After rebooting my laptop, I am getting "No Wi-Fi adaptor found". So I tried a few solutions mentioned in StackOverflow. But when I hit sudo lshw -C network

I am getting this in response

```
      product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 14.3
      bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
      version: 10
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
      configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
      resources: irq:16 memory:ed43c000-ed43ffff
 *-network:1
      description: Ethernet interface
      product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 1f.6
      bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
      logical name: eno2
      version: 10
      serial: 34:48:ed:03:b3:22
      capacity: 1Gbit/s
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
      configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
      resources: irq:172 memory:ed400000-ed41ffff
```

Also after hitting `rfkill list` I am getting a *no* in *Hard Blocked* for Wireless LAN.

```
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

There is no **logical name** for my wifi adaptor. So I am not able to use the `ip link set <logical name> up` command.

Is there any way I can enable the wifi adaptor on my laptop?

**Updates after running** `dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[   55.597391] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   55.605884] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   55.605886] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[   55.606116] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   55.666887] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x318
[   55.674157] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   55.674786] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[   60.743166] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[   60.743169] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[   60.743170] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
[   60.743262] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: a3708086 00100406 02800010 00800010 ed43c004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   60.743263] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 40308086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[   60.743264] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000040: 00928010 10000ec0 00100c10 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   60.743265] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000405 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   60.743266] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000080: 800f0011 00002000 00003000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   60.743267] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   60.743267] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000008 00804005 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   60.743268] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   60.743269] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000100: 14c00000 ff000000 000000ff 00462031 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[   60.743270] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   60.743271] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000140: 00000000 00000000 00000000 16410018 00000000 0001001e 00481e1f 00000000
[   60.743272] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[   60.743289] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 18489008 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   60.743290] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000010 0c000005 00000312 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0040
[   60.743293] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[   60.743296] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   60.743298] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   60.991149] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   60.991158] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   60.991160] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x716CCC21 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   60.991162] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   60.991164] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x663AF427 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   60.991166] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   60.991168] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC6D4126C | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   60.991170] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC62B4DBF | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   60.991172] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x65B2E760 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   60.991174] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x61FEFAE7 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   60.991176] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   60.991180] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   60.991184] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   60.991218] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   60.991263] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[   60.991447] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
[   61.003229] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I just edited my question after running the command. And Thanks!

Comment: It is suggested that a later kernel version and corresponding later firmware version may fix the issue. Please download and try a live session of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and tell us if the issue is fixed: `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 This happened to me once or twice too. Reboot fixed the issue. It some sort of a bug.

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: No @Pilot6 its installed with 1 OS and that's Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something random. Dont know how it worked for me.
Just followed the steps.

1.Restarted my Laptop.

2.Entered BOIS setup (F12).

3.Then inside the wireless section, I completely disabled WLAN.

4.When it booted up successfully, Restarted Laptop again.

5.Entered BOIS setup and enabled the WLAN.

Finally when the laptop turned on, everything was working fine again.